# run performSegueWithIdentifier inside a queue

Tags: ios, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to run a task in a new queue and then when this task is finish to inform to the VC to run a performSegueWithIdentifier to pass the next view controller.

In a method button I have this call:

```
  - (IBAction)previewButtonTouchedIn:(id)sender 
{    
     prepareDesign(self.imageToEdit,self.maskImageToPrint,self.drawingView,^(UIImage* imageReturn){

        self.previewDesignImage = imageReturn;

       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:PREVIEW_SEGUE sender:self];
    });
}
```

and the method called, contains:

```
   void prepareDesign(UIImage *imageToEdit,UIImage *maskImageToPrint,UIView *drawingView,  void (^block)(UIImage*)       
   {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


    //Here the task which I want to run in a new queue


        UIImage *imageSnapShot = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    //I have tested with dispatch_sync and dispatch_async.

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ block(imageSnapShot);});
    });
}
```

I have tested with

```
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ block(imageSnapShot);}];
```

instead of

```
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ block(imageSnapShot);});
```

And I have checked with breakpoint that the `performSegueWithIdentifier` is run with the main thread setting the breakpoint in the `performSegueWithIdentifier` call  and in the `prepareForSegue:sender:`.

The screen is simply frozen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It seems that the problem was the conde inside:

//Here the task which I want to run in a new queue

All my test drive me to think the problem is:

```
 [self.drawingView drawViewHierarchyInRect:viewPrintBase.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Sorry for not write all the code :S

Thanks!